# Vectorize Matlab/Octave code for string operation

Tags: matlab, octave

How do I vectorize the following Matlab/Octave code-

```
sentence='The quick brown fox';
l=findstr(sentence,' ');% One blank space
w=l(1);
first=sentence(1:w-1);
last=sentence(w:end);
```

I can combine the last two statements into one statement. Is there anything that can be done to convert the last four statements into one statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strtok`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFstrtok) will do what you're after.

```
>> [first, last] = strtok (sentence, ' ')
first = The
last =  quick brown fox
```

---

<sub>PS: Given the wording in your question, I feel compelled to point out that "one-liners" and "vectorisation" are two completely unrelated concepts.</sub>

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The comment. I assumed vectorization was converting a block of code into one line using vector operations. Could you tell me how I'm wrong?

Comment: Reducing the lines of code has nothing to do with anything (except perhaps readability, whether positively or negatively). Vectorisation refers to a number of techniques that replace traditional iterative techniques (e.g. 'for loops') that operate on one element at a time, with 'Matrix-based' operations which are optimally designed to work with matrices; the reason such operations are much faster is usually because they are redirected to optimal implementations under the hood (e.g. coded in c++), whereas 'for loops' are roughly equivalent to performing running lots of instructions one-by-one.

Comment: Read [the relevant section in the Octave Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Vectorization-and-Faster-Code-Execution.html#Vectorization-and-Faster-Code-Execution) if you want to learn more

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `strsplit` for extracting all the words in the sentence:

```
sentence='The quick brown fox';
words = strsplit(sentence, ' ');
first = words{1};
last = words{end};
```